# logOnce higher order function

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a function that takes another function as an argument, and returns a new version of that function that can only be called once.

The first function works, but the 2nd one doesn't work.

Why doesn't the 2nd function work, but can somehow still access the word without a function inside it like the first one?

```
var logOnce = once(console.log)    

function once(fn) {
  var call = true;
  return function(word) {
    if(call) {
      call = false;
      return fn(word);
    }
  }
}

function once(fn) {
  var call = true;
  if (call === true) {
    call = false;
    return fn;
  }
}


logOnce("foo");   ----> "foo"
logOnce("blue");  ----> "blue"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach doesn't work because it returns the same `fn`. In fact, it is equivalent to

```
function once(fn) {
    return fn;
}
```

Therefore, `once(console.log)` is just `console.log`, and you can call it as many times as you want.

The first approach works because you return a **different** function, which will call the original one or not depending on a variable.

Comment: thanks it makes a lot of sense stripped down like that